# JavaScript this is undefined when function called in a loop

Tags: javascript, scope, undefined

I have the following code with the behavior explained in the comments. What could be the reason why `"this"` is `undefined` in the anonymous function?

```js
const getLength = (str) => {
  return str.length
}

const getDefaultValues = () => {
  const valueGetters = {
    A: {
      AA: {
        xpath: 'path',
        getValue: function () {
          return getLength(this.xpath) // <---- this is not undefined and returns value
        }
      },
      AB: {
        xpath: 'path',
        getValue: function () {
          return getLength(this.xpath) // <---- this is not undefined and returns value
        }
      },
      AC: {
        xpath: 'path',
        getValue: function () {
          return getLength(this.xpath) // <---- this is not undefined and returns value
        }
      },
      AD: {
        xpath: 'path',
        getValue: function () {
          return getLength(this.xpath) // <---- this is not undefined and returns value
        }
      },
      AE: {
        xpath: 'path',
        getValue: function () {
          return getLength(this.xpath) // <---- this is not undefined and returns value
        }
      },
      GROSS: function () { // <--- when called in the loop, this returns 0 because all the ternary operators evaluate to false and return 0
        // console.log('this', this) // <---- this is undefined
        const aa = this?.AA ? this.AA.getValue() : 0
        const ab = this?.AB ? this.AB.getValue() : 0
        const ac = this?.AC ? this.AC.getValue() : 0
        const ad = this?.AD ? this.AD.getValue() : 0
        const ae = this?.AE ? this.AE.getValue() : 0

        return aa + ab + ac + ad + ae
      }
    }
  }

  console.log('Calling without looping', valueGetters.A.GROSS()) // <--- This prints the correct value for gross without any problem

  // get the numerical values from the getters
  const valueEntries = Object.entries(valueGetters).map(([key, defaultValueGetter]) => {
    return [
      key,
      Object.entries(defaultValueGetter).map(
        ([defaultValueKey, defaultValue]) => [
          defaultValueKey,
          typeof defaultValue === 'function' ? defaultValue() : defaultValue.getValue() // <--- I suspect that the problem is with this line
        ]
      )
    ]
  })

  return makeObject(valueEntries)
}

const makeObject = (arr) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    arr.map(([key, val]) => (Array.isArray(val) ? [key, makeObject(val)] : [key, val]))
  )
}

console.log(getDefaultValues())
```

Comment: Where is `OPERATING_COST` in `valueGetters`?

Comment: Where do you call `.GROSS()` in the loop?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is my 'this'? Using objects method as a callback function](/q/1085674/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just calling the function in the form `defaultValue()`, which doesn't provide a `this` context. You need to provide the `this` value explicitly, which you can do with `.call()`.

```
typeof defaultValue === 'function' ? 
    defaultValue.call(defaultValueGetter) : 
    defaultValue.getValue()
```

Comment: Holy... (I don't know if we're allowed to complete that on here). That worked!! Thank you!